# The app with reflection calls run fast only in profiler

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Long story short - I can't explain why my console app with Kestrel server runs fast only in profiler, `Debug` or `Release` - doesn't matter.

**The long story**

I created small message-based [framework](https://github.com/Indemos/Distribution) that can create instance of specific class and execute one of its methods based on the argument type used in this method. Pretty much like [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) framework. At the startup, the app gathers available assemblies and creates a [dictionary](https://github.com/Indemos/Distribution/blob/main/Distribution/Domains/Scene.cs#L186) where assembly name or a message type is the key and appropriate `MethodInfo` is the value. When specific message is sent, the relevant `MethodInfo` makes a method call via reflection.

**Message handler [sample](https://github.com/Indemos/Distribution/blob/main/Samples/Common/Actors/DemoActor.cs) that will be called via reflection**

```
public class DemoActor
{
  public virtual Task<DemoResponse> Create(CreateMessage message)
  {
    return Task.FromResult(new DemoResponse { Data = "Hello" });
  }
}
```

**Reflection call [sample](https://github.com/Indemos/Distribution/blob/main/Distribution/Domains/Scene.cs#L138)**

```
if (Processors.TryGetValue(descriptor, out MethodInfo processor))
{
  instance = Activator.CreateInstance(processor.DeclaringType); // cache 
  response = processor.Invoke(instance, message);
}
```

**Performance [check](https://github.com/Indemos/Distribution/blob/original/Samples/Client/Client.cs#L40)**

```
var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) scene.Send<DemoResponse>("Demo", message).Result;

stopWatch.Stop();
var ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
  ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
  ts.Milliseconds / 10);
Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
```

Preliminary testing showed that the simplest local call executed in the loop 100K times takes around 6 seconds. I immediately assumed that this is due to the reflection slowness and [replaced reflection](https://github.com/Indemos/Distribution/pull/1/files?diff=split&w=1#diff-210faea6c5a8493f40889f95901c0de63803cfa646152c2adf1c7c4de5928b5fR142) call with `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, then with `Expression.Compile`. This didn't make any difference, at all. Switching between `Debug` and `Release` mode also didn't make any difference.

Then, I tried to use built-in VS 2022 profiler, specifically, the one for `async` calls, and execution time magically dropped from 6 seconds to less than 1 second.

[image: Profiler]

**System**

Windows 10 Pro x64, Quad Core i7 2.4 GHz, SSD, RAM 32 GB, .NET 6.0, VS 2022 Preview 3

**Questions**

- Why there is no difference between reflection, delegates, and expressions?
- <s>Why there is no difference between `Debug` and `Release` configuration?</s>
- <s>What is the right way to test performance in this case?</s>

**Update**

Appeared to be I was always running build with attached debugger that was causing slowness. Published version runs as [fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12003677/437393) as profiler and testing performance with `StopWatch` should be enough in this case. Meanwhile, I still can't explain why there is no boost after switching from reflection calls to compiled delegates.

Comment: Your use of .Result seems suspect.

Comment: @DavidL This is a part of the sample app, not the library itself, and it's for demonstration purposes only. At the moment I'm not testing Sync vs Async. The question is why execution time changes when the code doesn't and it doesn't depend on how the call is being awaited, whether the thread is blocked or not. Profiler runs 6+ times faster even with the blocked thread

Comment: It's possible that your performance measurement is slower than the call itself.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-6/#reflection

Comment: @shingo Thanks. Informative. According to benchmarks and discussions, reflection is expected to be pretty close to direct calls and doesn't need optimization anymore?

Comment: No it's optimized and still slow. But I think it is faster than DynamicInvoke.