# C# TopShelf Service runs great with debugging; Incredibly slow without debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service, topshelf

Edit: This is still an issue but the program is not running slow as a service, it is running slow whenever NOT debugging.  Running the diagnostics withotu debugging produced the same slowness.  Peak cpu usage was 3%.  That being said, any help with why this application would run slower WITHOUT debugging would be incredibly helpful as I google down the answer :)

Using C# and nuget'd topshelf, I have made a filewatcher/mover.  There is an instance of filesystemwatcher which performs a long set of logic against a text document (between 100 kb > 8 MB).  As it reads this text document (on a UNC network location) it will move the lines to one of 2 output files.

While I run the application through Visual Studios 2015 Community in debug mode or release mode, all the file actions and movement are as instant as they can get.  Satisfied, I installed the application as a service on the same local machine.  I turn on the service, key the trigger, and it starts moving the text files....  50 kb every couple seconds.

1 MB file is taking a few minutes to parse through when it took a whopping 10 seconds when run through Visual Studios.  The service is logged in as me, the same user in Visual Studio.

Any ideas?  I have used topshelf for 3-4 other services, all utilizing filesystemwatcher or System.IO.FILE library (using the file library).

I can post some code if needed, just a bunch of if statements as it iterates through each line of text.  The key issue being:  works great from VS, not as a service.  Why??

P.S.  Just noticed that it took >4 minutes to move 1.4 mb's all to another file line by line, but went through all the logic after the move within the same SECOND.

I will post the snippet of topshelf configuration I am using, as it is not much:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator =>
        {
            hostConfigurator.Service<Service>(serviceConfigurator =>
            {
                serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(name => new ASNWatcher());
                serviceConfigurator.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
                serviceConfigurator.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
            });
            hostConfigurator.RunAsLocalSystem();

            hostConfigurator.SetDescription("HighRisk ASN Watcher");
            hostConfigurator.SetDisplayName("HighRiskASNWatcher");
            hostConfigurator.SetServiceName("HighRiskASNWatcher");
        });
    }
```

(yes, it says local system, I changed it post install to a proper user.)

Adding code that does the reading; very lite.

I am adding the piece of code that does the splitting:

```
     foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(fullPath))
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("ASIAUD"))
                {
                    foreach (var field in fileHelper856AUD.ReadString(line))
                    {
                        if (field.TradeID.TrimEnd() != TradeID && field.TradeID.TrimEnd() != CatalogTradeID)
                        {
                            logger.Info("Found thisTrade ID:  " + field.TradeID.TrimEnd());
                            thisorder = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logger.Info("Found thatTrade ID:  " + field.TradeID.TrimEnd());
                            thisorder = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (thisorder )
                {
                    try
                    {

                        File.AppendAllText(newfile1, line + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //write to log,  also send an email alerting IT.
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(newfile2, line + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            logger.Info("File Split Complete.  Deleting Original File...");
            File.Delete(fullPath);
```

Comment: It's really hard to say what's going on. You should add logging to your application and watch the log file during runtime. There can also be (an accidental) `Thread.Sleep` that you somehow missed during debugging. If you have many threads, double check that they aren't waiting much for each other.

Comment: Maybe the service has a low priority?

Comment: There is logging for each step, I added a piece of logging to the foreach as it steps through the document and it is doing all the lines, just incredibly 'slow'.  Logging doesn't show any difference between as a service or run through VS other than the timestamp grows a lot faster.  There are no sleeps.

Comment: @oleksii I added the snippet of code, no sleeps, nothing crazy, just read a line and if a variable is active, put it in this doc, if it's not, put it in this doc.

Comment: @mikeH can you expand on that?  I've never had to fiddle with priorities in the past.

Comment: It won't be thread or process priority - unless you see that your CPU usage is 100% for all the cores. Most of the time your PC will spend in Idle, meaning all threads with low priority have been executed. Check all your `catch` blocks -  add logging there, it can be a problem of permissions. When you debug application you run it as a user, say Admin. When you run a service it runs under different username, such as LocalSystem and that may not have permissions to do stuff.

Comment: @oleksii I don't see how a permissions issue would cause a file transfer to be slower?  It would either have permission to the file/location or not.  It does.  I've ran the service as 4 users, 2 don't have permission to the location and immediately failed.  
MikeH mentioned priority of the service, and someone near my cubicle mentioned service priority;  it sounds like THAT may be the problem as it is definitely not capping CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find some hints and get in the right direction through some other Stack articles once I discovered it wasn't the service piece that was hurting it, just running it without the profiler in general.

[Why does my program run way faster when I enable profiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964573/why-does-my-program-run-way-faster-when-i-enable-profiling/6629040#6629040)

> The reason is because when you run your application within Visual Studio, the debugger is attached to it. When you run it using the profiler, the debugger is not attached.
>
> If you press F5 to run your program, even with the Release build, the debugger is still attached.
>
> If you try running the .exe by itself, or running the program through the IDE with "Debug > Start Without Debugging" (or just press Ctrl+F5) the application should run as fast as it does with the profiler.