# Pre-load WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, lag, preload

My DataGrid(In a tab) has a lot of ColumnHeader and DataTrigger.
Everything is good until I select the tab for the first time, whole application lag for 5 seconds.
After that, there is no more lag.

So I was wondering if I can pre-load DataGrid first, then there won't be a lag.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Use Virtualization or MultiThreading.

Comment: Virtualization does help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.

This solves my issue. Because debugger slow down my application.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6629040/1563172

I also found the answer that maybe could solve leopold's issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765128/7382451

Comment: As Ramin commented in your answer, virtualization is the key to solve this. All your rows/columns are being loaded at the same time, right after entering the tab. The second answer you found is the one that probably will solve your issue. The first doesn't even seem related though.